# using loop to change class of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a loop that will change the class of every item in a list, but it seems that each time the loop access the list, it get's shorter after each itteration

for example:
html code:

```js
for(let i = 0; i<document.getElementsByClassName('list').length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('list')[i].className="student";
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Pete</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li>David</li>
  <li>Sarah</li>
  <li>Dan</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone please explain why is it happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Fix your code to be runnable first.

Comment: Your code has errors in it. Please correct them. Do you want to replace the class list with student? What is your question?

Comment: The logic also has an issue around incrementing `i` and reducing the number of elements that it will be iterating over.  You either need to store the results in a variable and loop over the variable, or use a while loop based off of the search length being greater than 0

Comment: live html collection!!!!! When you alter the class, it no longer lives in the collection!

Comment: live collection or not — you should not be calling `getElementsByClassName` every time through the loop.

Comment: Assigning to `className` will remove any other classes that might also/already be on the element. It's generally better to use [`classList.add('newclass')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a live html collection. So when you alter index [0] it is dropped from the collection. So the item that was in [1] is not at [0].

You either loop backwards, you use a while loop, or use modern way with `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1):

I think @epascarello answer explains, this is the additional part with querySelectorAll

> getElementsByClassName returns a live html collection. So when you
>   alter index [0] it is dropped from the collection. So the item that
>   was in [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is not at [0].
>
> You either loop backwards, you use a while loop, or use modern way
>   with querySelectorAll

you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
let c = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
let i;
for (i in c) {
  c[i].className = 'student';
}
```

```css
.student{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Pete</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li>David</li>
  <li>Sarah</li>
  <li>Dan</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the parent element, you should get all `li` and not an`ul`.

Try this:

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list li')
for(let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].classList.add("student");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use higher order function:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("list")].forEach((element) => {
  element.className = "student";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

two things can be improved in your code; first using storing result of  `document.getElementsByClassName` in a variable and since reading DOM is expensive, and second thing is to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`; here is your code re-written:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

setTimeout(()=>{
  for(let i = 0; i<elements.length;i++){
      elements[i].className="student";
  }
}, 2000)
```

```css
.list{color: red}
.student{color: blue}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
 <li>John</li>
 <li>Pete</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
 <li>David</li>
 <li>Sarah</li>
 <li>Dan</li>
</ul>
```